# why doesn't pushstate save dom state?

Tags: javascript, pushstate

Can someone explain why pushstate doesn't cause dom state to be saved?

Eg. I go to a page, click a link that causing a pushstate, I navigate to a completely different page (without pushstate) and hit the back button. I'd expect to see the dom post pushstate, instead you see the original rendered dom. Wouldn't that be more consistent with what changing the URL actually does?

I understand in most cases people are building web apps that use JSON data + client side rendering so it generally doesn't matter but why isn't dom state saved?

Comment: Hitting the back button loads the (cached if available) source and scrolls to where you were. It doesn't 'remember' entered or modified anything because that is a huge potential security risk. If you want things remembered, use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage)

Comment: Can you provide an example of why it's a security risk? I could in theory store the entire dom in localStorage and restore it but my implementation would be obviously slow.

Comment: A page that requires a login but deletes cookies on unload, on a shared computer. Or anything that has a session timeout.

Comment: ah, very good point. I mean I agree that's an issue, but that is already in issue with http http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Inconsistent_state_on_client_and_server that requires manual intervention. It's also something you have to manage if you're using pushstate. I still feel like it should have been something considered in the spec. There could be a rule like "if any xhr requests have no-cache headers" storing dom state should not be permitted (but that restriction should exists on pushed state as well) or a parameter to disable dom state saving.